# Android Canvas Path.OP Operation unexpected behaviour and randomly "freeze" with no output

Tags: android, image, animation, canvas, path

I'm improving my app to avoid overdraw and win more frames/second.

1. I need to first build a custom shape which I'm trying to do by creating different paths and joining them through Path.Op.Union in just one.
2. Then, I intersect that Path through canvas.clipPath(shape, Region.Op.INTERSECT); and over it I want to draw a bitmap
3. The goal is to have the bitmap with the shape of the final path/shape that in each draw cycle changes. It's a circle with custom deformations basically, but with an image embedded in it.

   ```
   DeformationCircleAnimator[] animation_vectors = new DeformationCircleAnimator[AnimationConfig.MAX_DEFORMATIONS_PER_CIRCLE];

   [...]

   Path shape =  createShapePath(); //1. Building the custom shape
   canvas.clipPath(shape, Region.Op.INTERSECT); //2. Adding shape to canvas to mold the bitmap into it
   canvas.drawBitmap(image, x1, y1, null); //3. positioning image in canvas and drawing it

   private Path createShapePath() {
       Path shape_path = new Path();
       shape_path.addCircle(circle.ball.centerX(), circle.ball.centerY(), circle.radius()*AnimationConfig.THUMBNAIL_SIZE_RATIO, Path.Direction.CW);

       for(int i=0; i!=animation_vectors.length; i++) {
           PointF[] points=animation_vectors[i].getThumbnailPoints();
           Path path = createDeformationPath(points);
           Log.d("DeformationController", "    After a while randomly blocks in this next step ");
           shape_path.op(path, Path.Op.UNION);
        }

       return shape_path;
   }

   private Path createDeformationPath(PointF[] points) {
       Path path = new Path();

       for(int i=0; i!=points.length; i++) {
           Log.d("DeformationController", "    Points("+i+"): " + points[i].toString());
       }

       path.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
       path.cubicTo(points[1].x, points[1].y, points[2].x, points[2].y, points[3].x, points[3].y);
       path.close();

       return path;
   }
   ```

I have an animation running meaning that my custom view is invalidated aprox from 20ms to 20ms and in the the draw method of my view I call a method that run this code.

I'm having two problems.

1. First Problem
   After a while, the app freezes in the the line "shape_path.op(path, Path.Op.UNION);" after I call the method createShapePath. It doesn't crash, but it stays there and nothing happen anymore until android os ask me if I want to wait for the task or kill the app. It's a strange behaviour since sometimes happens after 1, 2, [..] or even 5 seconds.

[image]

2. Second Problem - The Path.Op.UNION have an unexpected behaviour

I was expecting that basically builds just one shape that was a circle with deformations but, strangely, it doesn't make me the union of the paths, it appears that sometimes it cuts it on collision points.

**Expected Behaviour**

[image]

**What's happening - The unexpected behaviour:**

(Please note that these images represents different moments)

[image]

[image][image]

notes:

1. I post these 2 problems into same post cause probably they are connected!
2. If I draw the complete path (and not the bitmap) the result is exactly the same meaning that the problem is when I'm building the complete Path.
3. I know that I can build a bitmap and use "paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));" and then draw this bitmap to obtain the same result but this is to slow which puts my frame rate below 15. (I need more frames per second)

Thanks so much for your help!

***********UPDATE***************

I'm adding some debug. The following points are some of the ones that I use in cubic operation. In fact, they are randomly generated:

```
[After running for some seconds, meaning that this is the part that the app decided to freeze - in this run]
10-17 15:18:30.200 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:    button-1> CreateShapeCicle  : 5 | 889
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(306.50906, 250.12515)
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(192.68051, 262.03217)
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(171.2101, 419.32123)
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(276.74606, 461.8999)
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(230.44182, 425.0678)
10-17 15:18:30.201 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(287.66864, 506.88214)
10-17 15:18:30.202 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(442.31085, 447.52573)
10-17 15:18:30.202 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(430.09357, 348.4287)
10-17 15:18:30.202 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(320.0, 470.7)
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(434.83334, 472.7612)
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(476.29462, 320.0204)
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(375.35, 264.13098)
10-17 15:18:30.203 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(400.96085, 284.50278)
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(323.55612, 198.45067)
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(183.68585, 271.02948)
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(212.13724, 384.90207)
10-17 15:18:30.204 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(222.2577, 308.0295)
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(165.74612, 409.8604)
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(280.00156, 518.0191)
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(378.66205, 453.8789)
10-17 15:18:30.206 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.208 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:    button-2> CreateShapeCicle  : 5 | 890
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(733.8789, 418.66205)
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(796.7874, 321.89615)
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(689.6939, 205.83849)
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(588.0295, 262.2577)
10-17 15:18:30.211 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(573.3791, 271.59106)
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(489.8216, 332.2361)
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(551.4591, 484.26596)
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(653.4909, 469.87485)
10-17 15:18:30.212 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(584.65, 455.86902)
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(683.1479, 515.1188)
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(794.6875, 402.43094)
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(735.869, 304.65)
10-17 15:18:30.213 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Unioning Done 
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(0): PointF(532.1372, 384.90207)
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(1): PointF(555.6682, 495.87653)
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(2): PointF(714.53656, 501.81717)
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     Points(3): PointF(745.8629, 392.36554)
10-17 15:18:30.214 27904-27904/com.test.app D/DeformationController:     After a while randomly blocks in this next step 
FREEZED
```

******* UPDATED for problem number 2 - unexpected behaviour *******

I'm adding two screenshots of different moments but now with 2 paths joined only: The circle and one cubic Path. If you look into the pictures you can easily figure out what is the circle and what is the deformation. As you may see the behaviour is really strange cause it seems a XOR and not an Union (I also tried with addPath).

[image]

[image]

note: The version of android is kitkat: 4.4.2

Comment: can you use `Path#addPath` and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: addPath solves the problem nº 1, meaning that it stops freezing but the second problem still exists, behaviour continues unexpected. I was looking to avoid overdraw. I will continue to do some tests. Thanks

Comment: i'm not 100% sure what your problem #2 is, but did you try `setFillType`?

Comment: I updated the question for the problem n 2 be even more clear. I'm also recorded a video of the problem here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx62BNfVLJZDckRtZWVLcFpVTWc

Comment: Yes, I tried setFillType and didn't work.

Comment: ok, i see it now: cubic path can never interpolate to a perfect circle: instead of cubic path try arcs

Comment: Before I do what you recommended, I've made some tests with cubic path and arc (instead of a circle) and the behaviour still exists. Probably it's not only with perfect circles then. I'll try to test what you recommend meaning that I have to do manually the Bessel curve with an arc. Do you have any link to support your affirmation? I would love to learn more about it. Thanks.

Comment: sure, though i dont understand a single word here: http://spencermortensen.com/articles/bezier-circle/ ;-) but you could try a frame on the top right that reads: `"A good cubic Bézier approximation to a circular arc is:"`

Comment: Thanks but I was talking about the fact that "cubic path can never interpolate to a perfect circle" :)

Comment: the link above proves that, doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry pskink, but probably I'm misunderstanding something here. What I'm trying to understand is why the operation Union doesn't work. For example, with the same code, if I use other operation than Union it works (Difference for example or ReverseDifference). Why the Union doesn't work? Union should be joining both paths. I don't see why the function doesn't do the job.

Comment: i have no idea how that union internally works

Comment: There is a chance that union is confused as to what is "inside" and what is "outside". If you change the order or maybe the circle direction it may help (but I am not familiar with the implementation of union as well).

Comment: I tried to change the order already in the past and the result was exactly the same..... I'm trying to figure out out the Op method works with Union.

Comment: Finally it's working :) Ok, so instead of drawing a circle through "path.addCircle" or even using path.addArc (those don't work), I draw a circle Path through Oval. After it, I joined the cubic paths by path.addPath and that's it. The path.Op doesn't work well even with path.drawOval. Please add this into an answer and I will accept it since I figured out the solution due to your inputs. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can hurt your performance is that you keep allocating Path objects and computing their values while you are drawing. Perhaps you can instead create an array of possible Path objects and cycle through them depending on how many milliseconds have passed since the Animation started. Looking at all the Paths can also help you pin point exactly what you are doing wrong with the odd objects (my first guess is that cubicTo() is doing something you don't expect, but without seeing the actual input it is hard to tell).

Comment: I'll give a try to pre create a buffer of Paths and reuse it. I added some debug on example points that I use in the cubic operation. Though, those values are generated randomly, meaning that they have low probability of being exactly the same in each cycle. Either way, the problem is not in the points generated cause it works in the less efficient app that I have where I use a Bitmap and PorterDuffXfermode to do the effect. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try turning off hardware acceleration? I've seen cases where it does not behave as expected.

Comment: I tried your first guess by having cache Path objects and reuse it and I tried also with hardware acceleration off and the problem still remains.

Comment: Did you try on other devices/higher OS?

Comment: So, if I try in a higher OS in a different device the behaviour is much better but I still notice some bad behaviour. I'll post the result tonight. @pskink wrote that cubic path can never interpolate to a perfect circle (i tried with not perfect circles too) so probably this is the problem. I'll make some tests.

Comment: That was my first guess :)

Comment: I figured out now that when joining even different cubic paths it gives the same problem meaning that the problem is in the Union. It was indeed your first guess. Do you imagine the reason? I'll post here the videos of the behaviour.

Comment: Joining two cubic paths: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx62BNfVLJZDaUNlMnRoOXZIdEE  . Please note that the two paths is supposed to survive only by a few seconds and they should grow and reduce starting and ending in random points on each life. Though, you easily notice that in the middle of the life they blink. It's burning my brain. Anyway, I know that is hard to figure out what is the problem so I'll dig in it for some more time. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Joining one cubic path to a circle result: http://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx62BNfVLJZDeEpINGRUUi1jcWM

Comment: Thanks for your help man. I figured out the solution already. Please read the last comment that I've made to @pskink (if you are interested to know the closing of this post).